# What's with user366, user350, user377 etc. ?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

When I look at the [newest users](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newest), I see some suspiciously similar names (user366, user350, user377).

Unlike other names though, when I type them into the "Type to find users" box, they don't appear in the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the generated user names, just incrementing up from the first user-- everyone has a similar name, till they change it in their preferences under 'Display Name'.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what scw said, note that unregistered users won't show up in the user list.